# allow controller method access for multiple middlewares laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, middleware, guard

I am working on a project with multiple authentication that has admins, students and teachers as three levels of authentication. I have changed default authenticable user model to student and added two more authenticable models that have their own logins.

I have the CourseController as follows:

```
    use App\Course;
        use App\Invoice;
        use Illuminate\Http\Request;
        use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

    class CourseController extends Controller
    {

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->middleware('auth', ['only' => ['index']]);
            $this->middleware('auth:teacher', ['only' => ['index']]);
            $this->middleware('auth:admin', ['only' => ['index', 'create', 'store', 'edit', 'update', 'delete', 'search', 'destroy']]);
        }

        /**
         * Display a listing of the resource.
         *
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function index()
        {
            $data = Course::get();
            if (Auth::user()->role == 'admin') {
                return view('admin.course.index', compact('data'));
            } elseif (Auth::user()->role == 'student') {
                return view('student.course.index', compact('data'));
            } elseif (Auth::user()->role == 'teacher') {
                return view('teacher.course.index', compact('data'));
            }
        }
    }
```

config/auth.php as follows:(default guard is student)

```
'defaults' => [
        'guard'     => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'students',
    ],    

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver'   => 'session',
            'provider' => 'students',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver'   => 'token',
            'provider' => 'students',
        ],

        'admin' => [
            'driver'   => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],


        'admin-api' => [
            'driver'   => 'token',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],

        'teacher' => [
            'driver'   => 'session',
            'provider' => 'teachers',
        ],


        'teacher-api' => [
            'driver'   => 'token',
            'provider' => 'teachers',
        ],
    ],
```

**My problem:**

I want CourseController@index to be accessible for all three guards and pass the $data to their respective view. How would I modify the CourseController so that I can achieve this?? Please help

If you have any other ideas you can suggest me that too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the awesome submission! I ran into this problem myself a little while back and realized that doing things in just middleware was not the way to go.

I found that using Gates and Policies where the best route to take. So basically what this means is, each User has a Role, that Role has a Permission, and you are able to use the Blade `@can` directive to restrict access to certain parts of your site.

You can also use the `middleware('can:accessCourse')` method chaining in your `web.php` routes file (HTTP Routes Definition File) to make sure that the route is 'locked down' so to say. If you're using the `Route::resource` definition, then you can add the line `$this->authorize('course.index');` to your index public function.

Using the constructor on your controller is great, but you should only use one middleware for that. I.E. `$this->middleware('auth:admin');` Then once that person has 'admin' access, you can check to see if they have the Role and subsequent Permissions to do whatever it is you want.

Heres a short diagram I drew up showing what's going on in the background and to summarize all the stuff I just said.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uAcL7awPdxVai590WNuJFvDM_wIpsuYo/view?usp=sharing

Also BitFumes on Youtube has a tutorial series on how to create Admin Roles, Permissions, Defining Gates, Adding Policies, and using 'can' middleware on your Routes! Thats where I learned from myself! Now, he might be a little hard to understand as English isn't his first language, but he knows his stuff!

This link starts half way through a playlist about making a Blog, and starts with making administrator roles! :P

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aY7X5v37Ebk&index=25&list=PLe30vg_FG4OTELVqQgHaMaq2oELjpSWy_

Hope that this answer has helped you and guided you towards finding a solution to your problem!

Comment: Great I'm glad I could be of assistance! :D

Answer (score 2):

I think it's better to do it via route.

**For student guard:**

`Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
   Route::get('student.course.index', 'CourseController@index');
 });`

**For teacher guard:**

`Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:teacher']], function () {
   Route::get('teacher.course.index', 'CourseController@index');
 });`

**For admin guard:**

`Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:admin']], function () {
   Route::get('admin.course.index', 'CourseController@index');
   //other routes
 });`